# How do I omit <remote> and <ref> in 'git push'?

Tags: git

When I'm on master, I only have to type 'git push' to push commits to the remote repo. I wish I could do so when I'm on another branch, without specifying the remote name and the branch name. Like that:

Now:  `git push origin experimental:origin/experimental`

Need: `git push`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should edit your `.git/config` file. There should be already set something like this:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Simply copy the group and edit according to your needs. For example, you could have:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "experimental"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/experimental
```